# How can I send specific files to a specific location with Jenkins publish over ssh?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, cicd

I have a Jenkins build process also produces a few text files about the code that was just built. I want to transfer these files, and only these files, to another server at a particular URL and location on the filesystem. How can I perform this transfer with Jenkins' PublishOverSsh?

That is, how can I use PublishOverSsh to run something like this `scp` command:

```
scp *.txt name@server.xyz:/path/to/file
```